# Get cell contents on drop down change

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 9 sheets. On sheet 8 (Inv Inq) I have a drop down list created from Form Controls. The list is being auto-populated from a named set. When a category from the drop down is selected, cell K5 is being updated with a number.

I am trying to capture that number in VBA. The closest I am coming is with the Worksheet_SelectionChange event - but that fires every time a cell is clicked. I want to fire an even anytime K5 changed. I have tried also, Worksheet_Calculate and Worksheet_Change. Worksheet_Change is closer to what I want - but that only fires if the content is manually changed and the cell is clicked off.

Comment: Assign a macro to the form control drop down.

Comment: Well that was simple...thank you!